# Matching cyrillic characters that look like latin characters?

Tags: php, regular-expression

I would like to identify Cyrillic characters that look like Latin characters and have a list I can refer to.

How would I go about that using PHP and regular expressions?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regular expression pattern that matches all Cyrillic characters that look like Latin characters, regardless of case:

```
[А-Яа-я]*[AaЕеKkMmHhOoPpTtXx][А-Яа-я]*
```

Explanation:

`[А-Яа-я]*` matches zero or more Cyrillic characters (capital or lowercase)
`[AaЕеKkMmHhOoPpTtXx]` matches any of the Latin characters that have Cyrillic look-alikes, regardless of case.

These characters are:

```
    ◦ A (А)
    ◦ a (а)
    ◦ E (Е)
    ◦ e (е)
    ◦ K (К)
    ◦ k (к)
    ◦ M (М)
    ◦ m (м)
    ◦ H (Н)
    ◦ h (н)
    ◦ O (О)
    ◦ o (о)
    ◦ P (Р)
    ◦ p (р)
    ◦ T (Т)
    ◦ t (т)
    ◦ X (Х)
    ◦ x (х)
```

Note: This pattern assumes that you are using Unicode encoding. If you are using a different encoding, the Cyrillic characters and their corresponding Latin look-alikes may be different.